# How the hotspot problem in ranged sharding can be solved?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I can't seem to find the answer I am looking for. Like do shards just keep getting sharded into smaller shards? This doesn't seem like the answer to me, because then the shards can infinitely get sharded?

Comment: Did you read this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning/?